# What does "object" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> His friends were those of his own blood or those whom he had known the longest; his affections, like ivy, were the growth of time, they implied no aptness in the object.
>   -- *Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde*

The last sentence is really strange to me. What does "aptness" and "object" mean in here? What does the author try to express?

Comment: But there *is* only one sentence in that quotation …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Object* refers to *affection*, the *object of his affections*, that is *his friends*.  The idea is that it didn't really matter if the friends he had suited him.  The friendships he developed were left to chance, kinship, and time.  In the end, they had grown on him like ivy does on a tree.

Here's a longer extract from Stevenson's book that gives a little more context:

> - It is the mark of a modest man to accept his friendly circle ready-made from the hands of opportunity; and that was the lawyer’s way. His friends were those of his own blood or those whom he had known the longest; his affections, like ivy, were the growth of time, they implied no aptness in the object. Hence, no doubt, the bond that united him to Mr. Richard Enfield, his distant kinsman, the well-known man about town.

Comment: He felt friendship for those people because he had known them for a long time, not because they were especially suitable friends for him.

Answer (score 0):

An extract from *Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde*? It would be best perhaps to explain friendship in the context of those who love their friends without question, and are comfortable in among them regardless of who their friends are and what they may be doing at any given point of time.

In the instant case, the speaker states that he has affection for his friends with who he has grown closer as years have gone by. To him it matters not what they may be or their activities per se. To him what matters most is his friendship with them and their company alone.